# Converting python files with media content to .exe

Tags: python

I was trying to convert my .py file to a .exe file via py2exe.

Here is my script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

 setup(name="Hyper Operating System",
      description="Private OS system",

scripts=[r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\login2.py"],
data_files=[(r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
           [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\012_restart- 128.png"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\account.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
           [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\background.png"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
          [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\background1.png"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
          [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\calendar.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\check.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\com.png"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
          [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\computer.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\custom.py"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
           [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\download.jpg"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\file.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\file1.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\files.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
           [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\firewall.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\icon.ico"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\install.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
           [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\installed.png"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
          [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\internet.png"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\loading.gif"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
           [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\loading2.gif"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\login.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\login2.py"]),
          (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\manager.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\menu.png"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\notepad.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\open.png"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\options.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
           [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\password.png"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
          [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\password_database.txt"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\restart.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\search.png"]),
          (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\setting.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
           [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\shutdown.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\signup.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\store.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\test.py"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
          [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\testcustom.py"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\tm.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\update.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
           [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\user-sign.png"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
          [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\username.png"]), (
          r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login",
          [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\user_signup.png"]),
          (r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login", [r"c:\users\neel-_000\desktop\python\login\wifi.png"])],
```

)
However, every time i run the program I get this error code:

```
  usage: test.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
  or: test.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
  or: test.py --help-commands
  or: test.py cmd --help
```

error: no commands supplied
Thanks in advance! If anyone can edit the script and repost it, that would be amazing

Comment: I've tried Nuitka, py2exe and PyInstaller.  PyInstaller seems to work the best once an app gets complex.

Answer (score -1):

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is probably the way to go.